# Solving simultaneous equations with 2 unknowns and modulus

Tags: linear-algebra

PS: Try answering this question without graphing the equations.

> If $|x|+x+y=5$ and $x+|y|-y=10$, what is the value of $x+y$? 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5?

Squaring LHS and RHS didn't seem realistic.

$|x|+x+y=5$

$2|x|+2x+2y=10$

$x+|y|-y=10$

$2|x|+2x+2y=x+|y|-y$

$|y|-2|x|=x+3y$

That's as far as I could go initially.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Try to follow the hints given and show your work? Do you know the definition of absolute value?

Comment: @5xum Apologies for not showing my own working. I only replaced the equations within each other, which always end up with the LHS equating to RHS. First time asking questions here, truly sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Instead of apologizing for a mistake, *fixing* the mistake would go a lot further in convincing us you are a hones poster.

Comment: @CheongJianYan Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

If $y \ge 0$, then the second equation gives $x=10$. Then the first equation gives $y=-15$, a contradiction. Hence we have $y<0$.

If $x \le 0$ the first equation shows $y=5$, hence, by the second eqaution , we get $x=10 >0$, a contradiction. Thus we have $x>0$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: When x > 0 and y < 0 2x + y = 5, x - 2y = 10, x = 4, y = -3, x + y = 1 Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let distinguish the cases

- $x\ge 0, \quad y \ge 0 \implies \begin{cases}|x|+x+y=5\implies x+x+y=5\implies y=-15\\\\x+|y|-y=10\implies x+y-y=10\implies x=10\end{cases}$
- $x\ge 0, \quad y < 0\implies \begin{cases}|x|+x+y=5\implies x+x+y=5\\\\x+|y|-y=10\implies x-y-y=10\end{cases}
  \implies 
  \begin{cases}2x+y=5\\\\x-2y=10\end{cases}\implies 
  \begin{cases}4x+2y=10\\\\2y=x-10\end{cases}\implies 
  \begin{cases}4x+x-10=10\\\\2y=x-10\end{cases}\implies 
  \begin{cases}x=4\\\\2y=4-10\implies y=-3\end{cases}$
- $x< 0, \quad y \ge 0$
- $x < 0, \quad y < 0\implies \begin{cases}|x|+x+y=5\implies -x+x+y=5\implies y=5\\\\x+|y|-y=10\implies x-y-y=10\implies x=20\end{cases}$

Comment: I managed to determine scenario 1 and 4 as invalid as it contradicts each other in the equation. How do you distinguish scenario 2 and 3?

Comment: @CheongJianYan I add some detail